# Why can't I modify the response of this post request via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I have a login form, that when submitted will redirect to the homepage `/`.

I would like the form to have the same behaviour except that when I receive the response back from the server, which comes in the form of HTML data, I can **modify** that HTML data so that after the redirect occurs, the homepage will show the modified HTML:

```
$(#login-form).submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(this);
  var user = $("#username").val();
  var passwd = $("#password").val();
  var url = $form.attr("action");
  var posting = $.post(url, { username: user, password: passwd });
  posting.done(function(data) {
    $(data).find("#logged-user").text("user777");
    $('html').html(data);
  });
});
```

In the above snippet of code, when say `user111` logs in, then there's a span tag `<span id="logged-user"></span>` that displays the name of the logged in user.

However, when I try to manipulate this span tag so it shows the name of a different user via `$(data).find("#logged-user").text("user777");` it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: You're not modifying the data, you're creating a DOM from it, modifying it, and doing nothing with it. You need to append it somewhere in your page: https://jsfiddle.net/unvdLj98/2/

Comment: So instead of `window.location.replace("./")`, I'm rendering the HTML response via `$('html').html(data);`. However, the issue still persists - it still says `user111` as logged in.

Comment: _“modify that HTML data so that after the redirect occurs, the homepage will show the modified HTML”_ - the redirect means a new page gets loaded, meaning everything you are doing in the current page with JavaScript, will be gone by then. You would have to store your modified HTML somewhere, so that you can read it in the document that gets redirected _to_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
posting.done(function(data) {
  var tmp = $('<div>' + data + '</div>');   // Create a temporary DOM
  tmp.find("#logged-user").text("user777"); // Modify it
  $('html').html( tmp.html() );             // Get its HTML, and use it
});
```

or simply:

```js
posting.done(function(data) {
  $('html').html(data);
  $("#logged-user").text("user777");
});
```